# Is re-using a structs own members in initialization reliable? (C99)

Tags: c, c99

I recently saw a warning while compiling C99 code that gave me pause to question if this is undefined behavior or not.
*(since I build on various platforms and only an older compiler version shows this warning).*

eg:

```
struct Vector { float x, y; };

void func(float a) {
    struct Vector test = { .x = a, .y = test.x + 1 };
    printf("%f %f\n", test.x, test.y);
}
```

With Clang 3.9.0 and GCC5.3 (on Linux) the code compiles without warnings.
However with Clang 3.4.1 (on FreeBSD), I get the following warning.

```
test.c:74:21: warning: variable 'test' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization [-Wuninitialized]
    .y = test.x + 1
     ^~~~
```

The code above should be the equivalent of:

```
void func(float a) {
    struct Vector test;
    test.x = a;
    test.y = test.x + 1;
    printf("%f %f\n", test.x, test.y);
}
```

It may work in one compiler yet still be undefined behavior, so my question is:

Providing the order of initialization assigns members before use.
Does C99 `struct` initialization re-use members and guarantee a predictable outcome?

Comment: C does not support partial initialisations. So all members are initialised **after** the initialiser finished. Note that an initialiser must be a _constant expression_. Please see the standard.

Comment: @Olaf, re-worked the question to be more clear.

Comment: Presuming you mean `struct Vector test = { .y = a, .x = .y + 1 };` ?

Comment: You will need to look at the documentation for each compiler. C89 requires initialization *in-order*, in ISO C99 you can give the elements in *any order*. Gnu provides this as an extension to C89, but that is not guaranteed for all compilers. So for C89, you will need to check, if it is C99 and *standards compliant*, then you can initialize in any order.

Comment: @David C. Rankin: C89/90 never allowed non-constant expressions in aggregate initializers, regardless of whether the object is static or local. For which reason the question does not even arise in C89/90. Most (if not all) compilers implemented non-constant initializers inside `{}` as an extension, so indeed in such cases it is a matter of consulting the compiler's documentation.

Comment: Please update the question to show the actual warning message, and to indicate which compiler produces it. I'd be surprised if *any* C compiler didn't reject this.

Comment: Corrected example and included warning.

Comment: Yes, and now that you've posted code that actually compiles (and generates the warning that you've shown), the answer is in the question itself. Using an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior.

Comment: @user3386109, notice that a newer version of the compiler doesn't warn.

Answer (score 4):

The proper syntax for self-referential initialization in this case would be

```
struct Vector test = { .y = a, .x = test.y + 1 };
```

Now, the language specification says

> **6.7.9 Initialization**
>
> **23** The evaluations of the initialization list expressions are
>   indeterminately sequenced with respect to one another and thus the
>   order in which any side effects occur is unspecified.

While 6.7.9/19 does seem to establish temporal ordering on subobject initialization, this ordering does not in any way define the order the evaluation of individual *initializer expressions*. Initializer expressions can be evaluated out of order. So, it does not guarantee that `test.y + 1` is evaluated after `.y = a` takes place. This means that your example is indeed undefined.

GCC expectedly produces a warning

```
'test.y' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

MSVC reports

```
warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'test' used
```

Comment: That doesn't say whether it's legal to use designated initializer names as r-values though.

Comment: I don't think 19 implies a temporal order, merely a logical order, only the last initializer for each subobject is used. For example given `struct Vector test = { .x = foo(), .y = 3, .x = 5 };` the function `foo` is never called.

Comment: @user3386109 The footnote to 6.7.9/19 seems to suggest that it may or may not be called (i.e. it's unspecified) although I don't see any normative text

Comment: @M.M Nevertheless, it's a logical ordering, not a temporal ordering.

Comment: Yes I was just responding to your comment "The function foo is never called"  (in fact it might be called)

Answer (score 3):

```
struct Vector { float x, y; };

struct Vector test = { .y = a, .x = .y + 1 };
```

That's a syntax error. The `.x =` (called a *designator*) must be followed by an *initializer*, which can be either an expression (specifically an *assignment-expression*) or a brace-enclosed *initializer-list* (with an optional trailing comma).

gcc 5.3.0 in particular reports this as a syntax error:

```
c.c: In function 'func':
c.c:6:41: error: expected expression before '.' token
     struct Vector test = { .y = a, .x = .y + 1 };
```

as does clang 3.7.1:

```
c.c:6:41: error: expected expression
    struct Vector test = { .y = a, .x = .y + 1 };
```

Your `.y + 1` presumably is intended to be an expression, but it isn't. There is no valid syntax to refer to a member of the object currently being initialized.

If your compiler supports this, it's a language extension, and you'll need to consult your compiler's documentation to see how it works.

Reference: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 6.7.9.